# convert x.y to a/b where x.y = a/b c#

Tags: c#

well i couldn't find the proper words to search for this so i apologize if it's too easy

i want to convert numbers like 0.142857 to 1/7, also notice that i only have 15 digits accuracy or in another words a 3.333333333333333 is 10/3 (which is mathematically wrong but it's practically good enough accuracy)

it's just i do some metrics and robotics calculations and i end up with something like

```
{-0.16271186440678; 0.111864406779661;  0.0474576271186441; \
0.0915254237288136; -0.125423728813559; 0.0983050847457627; \
0.159322033898305;  0.0779661016949152; -0.088135593220339; \}
```

while i would really prefer to end up with

```
{-48/295; 33/295; 14/295; \
 27/295; -37/295; 29/295; \
 47/295; 23/295; -26/295; \}
```

Comment: The proper words would be floating point to fraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Fraction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9078/Fraction-class-in-C) class from codeproject:

```
frac=new Fraction("6.25");    // we'll get 25/4
```

Answer (score 1):

The Thing that you are searching for is converting `Decimal` to `Fraction`. Easy way is to do your computations in floating point (or decimal) as long as you can before converting to integer. Here is an example of what you can do.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DecimalToFraction
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                decimal decimalValue = i / 1000m;       
                double doubleValue = i / 1000.0;    

                decimal numeratorDecimal = Math.Round(decimalValue * 1000m / 125m);     
                int numeratorFloat = (int) Math.Round(doubleValue * 1000.0 / 125.0);        
                int numeratorInt = (int)(doubleValue * 1000) / 125;     

                if (numeratorFloat != numeratorInt ||       
                    numeratorFloat != numeratorDecimal ||       
                    numeratorInt != numeratorDecimal)       
                {       
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,5}: Floating point: {1} Integer: {2} Decimal: {3}",       
                    i, numeratorFloat, numeratorInt, numeratorDecimal);     
                }       
            }       
        }       
    }
}
```